# Google Maps API House Number not Showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am trying to use Google maps autocomplete input to search for places and fill out the form fields. I do not get the house number (`Street Address` in the following form) from the API for the following address;

`30 Ellabay Crescent, Redland Bay QLD, Australia.`

[image]

If you try `30 Ellabella Court, South Morang VIC, Australia` it fills out the `Street Address` field properly;

[image]

Here my working example in JSFiddle;

https://jsfiddle.net/ssrpsathira/2n5s4qx0/4

I tried logging the output from the API call for this address when selected from the autocomplete dropdown and there was really no street address value in the address components of the API response and yet I am not sure why the street address number is shown in the autocomplete text.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or is it just the API behaviour? I really need to get this fixed to show the house number of the address.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please at least give a reason before downvoting?

Comment: Put the address you have a problem with in clear text so that one can copy it? Properly tag your question? Provide a working example (code snippet or fiddle)? Explain what you have tried, how you debugged it, and why you think it doesn't work? These might be some of the reasons why you get down-voted.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thanks for the tips and I have updated my question as suggested. Hope this would make sense more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is a proper answer but it would be too long to put this as a comment.

Why does one work and the other not? I don't know, and IMO, both should **not** work.

- `Ellabella Ct, South Morang VIC 3752` seems to have only numbers from 1 to 8 registered on Google Maps and this seems to be consistent with another data source: http://www.street-directory.com.au/vic/south-morang/ellabella-court
- `Ellabay Crescent, Redland Bay QLD` seems to have none. Try a search in the above website, it's not even on the map yet. Might be a new area? In any case, trying to reverse geocode any house on that street with Google Maps API returns just `Ellabay Crescent, Redland Bay QLD 4165`.

So I don't think there is anything wrong with your script, but maybe the data is just not up to date.

You can contribute to adding information on Google Maps. For that, please read https://www.localguidesconnect.com/t5/News-Updates/Exclusive-Edit-a-road-segment-in-Google-Maps/ba-p/149865

That still doesn't explain why it works in one case and not in the other when both street numbers seem to be unknown by Google...

You can file a new bug [in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853) if you think this should be corrected.